# Workaround for tensorflow's inability to assign in eager tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, variable-assignment

Eager tensors don't support assignment.  I need to do assignment.

```
a = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.choice(10, size = 12).reshape(3,4))
b = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([2,3]))
a[:,b] *= -1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-516f7e5d5213>", line 3, in <module>
    a[:,b] *= -1

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/covid_timeseries/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 777, in _slice_helper
    _check_index(s)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/covid_timeseries/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 666, in _check_index
    raise TypeError(_SLICE_TYPE_ERROR + ", got {!r}".format(idx))

TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor: id=3, shape=(2,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([2, 3])>
```

There is a suggestion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14132#issuecomment-483002522) for how to do a workaround:

```
new = original * mask + other * (1 - mask)
```

I'm having trouble making this work, because I can't figure out a way to create a mask that doesn't itself involve assignment!

I'd greatly appreciate some guidance that'd help me to implement this high-level approach, maybe something like this:

```
def tf_assign_workaround(tensor, index, newvals):
    ??
    return tensor_with_index_assigned_to_newvals
```

EDIT:  Here's the original, simpler example

```
a = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.choice(10, size = 12).reshape(3,4))
a[:,1] *= -1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-35-f8973c287624>", line 2, in <module>
    a[:,1] *= -1

TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: So what do you want to do? Negate the values in the second column?

Comment: The example above is just a dummy to demonstrate mechanically what I'm doing.  In my real problem, I've got a tensorflow model that I use to predict the parameters of a set of differential equations, and then I run through the diff eqs in a gradient tape.  The output of the diff eqs needs to be further modified by a different output of the net.  In short, it's really complicated. @thrushv89

Comment: Anyways, your problem is a more fundamental problem. You are trying to change the values of a `tf.Tensor` object. You can create a new `tf.Tensor` object by transforming an existing `tf.Tensor` object but you cannot edit a `tf.Tensor` inplace.

Comment: Hence the question. I need a workaround! How can I make a mask if I can't even assign to the mask?!?

Comment: The answer to your question would heavily depend on what you want in that mask. Can you provide a toy example? I could provide an example where I negate the second column. But sounds like that's an oversimplification of your problem.

Comment: Ideally it'd be general enough to handle fancy indexing.  I'll update.

Comment: it's maybe a naÏve question, but why can't you do the array operations using numpy and them just convert the resulting array to tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is the following:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> a = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.choice(10, size = 12).reshape(3,4))
>>> a
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 4, 2],
       [9, 3, 9, 1],
       [0, 9, 1, 4]])>
>>> mask = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.ones([3,4]).astype(int)*[1, 1, 0, 0])
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]])>
>>> a = a * mask - a * (1-mask)
>>> a
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[ 1,  1, -4, -2],
       [ 9,  3, -9, -1],
       [ 0,  9, -1, -4]])>
```

Note that you have to work with the same type, so the mask has to also be `int64`.

In case you want to make it generic and change the number of columns you want to mask:

```py
n=3
a = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.choice(10, size = 12).reshape(3,4))
mask = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.ones([3,4]).astype(int)*([1]*(4-n)+[0]*n))
a = a * mask - a * (1-mask)
```

and you'll get the last three columns with inverted signs:

```py
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[ 4, -1, -8, -5],
       [ 8, -6, -7, -9],
       [ 6, -3, -8, -5]])>
```